# PHP Site Will Not Send Mail to Own Domain

Tags: php, email

I've just added mail to my website hosted and the following is happening with mail:

- Email sent from private email (i.e. @gmail.com ) to @mydomain.com is received
- Email sent from PHP mail() to private mail is received
- Email sent from PHP mail() to @mydomain are **NOT RECEIVED**

My script that I am testing with is very basic:

```
 $to_address = "example@mydomain.com";
 $subject = "This goes in the subject line of the email!"; 
 $message = "This is the body of the email.\n\n"; 
 $headers = "From: example@mydomain.com\r\n"; 
 mail("$to_address","$subject","$message","$headers");
```

Is there a setting I need to change for this to work, or should be looking for?

I have checked junk mail and the mail is not being received there either.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the configuration of the mail software on your server, it's not a PHP issue.

Comment: Could be related to the mydomain.com setup. Some servers will discard mail that was sent from a server that is not whitelisted for the sender's domain. So while gmail may accept your mail, the MyDomain mail server may check if your PHP server is allowed to send mail on behalf of mydomain.com. If it's a different server (which is likely) then your server may block the mail for that reason. Anyway, you've proven that sending the mail in itself works, so there is no bug per se.

Comment: Does the PHP server run on the same server as the mailserver or a different one?